# how do you organize your namespaces?

Tags: .net, namespaces, project-organization

So I have logical entities (person, country, etc.), GUI elements / controls, data and navigation controllers / managers, then things like quad-trees and timers, and I always struggle with cleanly separating these things into logical namespaces.

I usually have something like this:

- Leviathan.GUI.Controls
- Leviathan.GUI.Views
- Leviathan.Entities
- Leviathan.Controllers (data and other stuff)
- Leviathan.Helpers (trees and other stuff)

Are there any good guides on this? I need to stop this mess.

Answer (score 3):

For applications

```
Company.Product.Tier.Sub.Sub
```

where I like to get Tier from Model, View, Controller or other established names (Data)

But for our controls, we end up with

```
Company.Product.LogicalFeatureGrouping
```

or

```
Company.Product.Addon
```

sometimes it's

```
Company.Product.LogicalFeatureGrouping.Addon
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid the "and other stuff" or "misc." categories,  If you are putting things in these categories you are failing to really organize them at all.

Comment: my thoughts, I just have a hard time finding a place for data structures that I use rarely, but are still necessary, like a QuadTree or BinaryTree...

Comment: Hey, sorry I just noticed the comment box!!  Just found this feature.  I would try hard to find something that is a common thread between at least 2 of them. Unless it shares nothing in common with any other namespace then it can be categorized. But oultine rule #1  no A without a B. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a namespace for every single tiers, like UI, business logic and database. It forces me to separate the tiers. I create other namespaces inside them according to system components.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the Java / python ideal that namespaces should follow the directory structure.

Comment: which would lead us to the following question: how you organize your directory structure :) I do the same, my namespaces are tied to the folder structure

Comment: I believe I read a standard somewhere about domains...like starting with a top level domain (org, com. gov, mil) and going down to project name and it's subcomponents.